# Two textareas but single CKEditor instance

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to create two textareas but single CKEditor instance. I want to use same CKEditor tool on two different textareas.
Anybody has any idea?

Comment: I can't even imagine what you're trying to do. You can create as many editors as you want. Why should different areas share the same editor? (and how?)

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what you want to achieve. What would be the benefit of that?

If you have one instance of ckeditor for the content of two textareas, you would not be able to divide the content of the textareas again afterwards.

On the other hand I see no disadvantage of having two instances for two textareas. They share the same configuration, so you have the same functionality for both textareas.

Comment: I am using CKEditor as Email Template. Currently I have two sections on the template. On the first section, user can input anything and has functionality to save. And on the second one, user can only edit for email (but don’t want to save). And also I want to combine both sections for email.

Comment: So you want to 'save' one field and 'email' both. In my opinion this is not related to ckeditor. The 'functionality' (saving the data and sending the email) is outside ckeditor, anyway. May I assume that you submit a form and process the data server-side?